# Is it possible to use invalid(non existing) Uri for JSON schema definition?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is it possible to use invalid(non existing) Uri for JSON schema definition?

So that I can specify it and use for versioning, without need to deploy it anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can always write whatever you want in a JSON. JSONschema is just an invented standard of documentation for JSON syntaxes. If you don't respect that standard, nothing is going to explode.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil - the question (as with all standards) is "if I do this, does it contradict the standard in a way that will confuse tools and other users and cause errors".  Even invalid JSON syntax won't literally combust your computer - but the question is obviously about trying to follow the standard so that tools and other users can meaningfully work with the schemas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A URL is expected to resolve to the resource, so if you say "this is the URL for the schema" then that URL should resolve to the schema.

However, URLs are not the only sort of URI - it sounds like a [URN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_name) might be what you want.  In contrast to a URL (uniform resource *location*), a URN (uniform resource *name*) is an identifier for a resource, but it doesn't carry a generic method to resolve it.

For example, the URN `urn:ietf:rfc:2648` is an identifier for RFC 2648, but there isn't a standard way to get the RFC text from just that URN (you'd need some kind of special service that knew about `urn:ietf:rfc:...` URNs).  If you used something like this, then it should (in theory) do what you want.

(You might run into trouble referencing one schema from another if your *library* is mistakenly assuming all URIs are URLs, but that would be a bug in your library.)